# Is high falsetto range means high chest range?

Tags: vocal-range, falsetto

I'm a male singer.  I've been studying voice and doing exercises for almost 1 month. My overall range is F2-D6. My problem is: I can only go up to F4 with my chest voice. For other notes, I have no choice but to use my falsetto. I have 2 questions;

1. I see other male singers who has same falsetto range with me (around C6-D6) and has very high chest voice range (around G5). Does the fact that our falsetto range is same mean our chest voice range is also same? (In other words, do I have potential to sing the high notes?)
2. Does falsetto range have connection with chest voice range? (In other words, Does high chest voice range means high falsetto range or does high falsetto range means high chest voice range?)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions, no, there is no precise relationship between each person's normal (*) and falsetto ranges. They both depend on several factors: anatomy, technique, state of mind, etc., and what each person can achieve with or without falsetto is highly variable. So it's not very useful (to say the least) to compare your range with other singers, except to try to understand what technique they use to achieve certain results.

If you practice correctly you'll improve both your normal and falsetto ranges, as the most important factors to good singing, like breathing, posture, abdominal support, relaxation, and others, will help with both modes of singing.

BTW, a 2 octave range is quite good to begin with, and F2 to F4 is almost the minimum required for a choir baritone, so not so bad at all. You should work on your high AND low registers, not just the high register and with practise you may extend them both, though more one way or the other it's impossible to predict.

(*) I prefer not to use the term "chest voice" as, though historical, it is not very correct. All the main resonance parts of the whole body contribute, in different degrees, to the production of vocal sound, be it "normal" register or falsetto. Falsetto is not the result of resonance existing only in the head, but it's a different mode of vibration of the vocal folds.

Comment: Anecdotally… I have no distinct falsetto range at all. If I can hit a note I can hit it in both full voice & falsetto. I have no range above that at all.

Comment: @Tetsujin The "normal" voice can also more technically be referred to as the "modal" voice  (which, of course, means "normal")

Comment: @JudyN. - sorry, I'm completely untrained - been singing 50 years & still don't know what any of it is actually called;) Thank you.

Comment: @Tetsujin sorry I don't know why my reply tagged you! It was just a general comment on the answer

Comment: @JudyN. Tagged ya back! ;) No worries at all. :)